# Can telescopes under $200 help you see saturn clearly by eye without editing the image on a computer?

Tags: telescope, amateur-observing, optics, mirror

I had a telescope that only cost 50 dollars  for viewing the moon and it was good for that but the planet's were always badly out of focus. I am thinking of getting a better telescope for up to $200 but reviews on YouTube of these telescopes  usually say they are good but after taking videos and superimposing the best frames on one another.  Can a cheap telescope give clear views of Saturn or Jupiter without the need for making videos or taking photos?

Comment: I assume you mean in the US, but perhaps consider writing explicitly which country you're in, as this is an international community.

Comment: I can tell that in my country, where everything is more expensive than in the US (except getting sick), you should be able to find a 200 USD telescope that will show you the rings of Saturn, although it will look very small.

Comment: Lots depends on what you mean by "clear".  Photo processing can bring out a lot of detail that is difficult or impossible to catch by eye, when the image is constantly shifting/distorting from atmospheric variations.  A $200 telescope will let you see the most prominent bands on Jupiter, for example, and maybe the Great Red Spot on an excellent night, but visually you can't see all the detail you might in well-stacked photos from the same telescope.

Comment: A 100mm or wider reflector might serve pretty well. Avoid the ones with short tubes.

Comment: @pela I am in the uk.

Comment: In the UK we use pounds sterling, not dollars.  I suggest you rephrase your question to use pounds.

Comment: Short answer is no. Such low-priced telescopes are toys at best. I don’t mean you can’t enjoy them, but their performance will always be disappointing. It is worth saving up and investing in a better instrument that will cost around 500–1,000 £ at least, if not more.

Comment: @James K IS dollars are the internationally accepted standard that most people are familiar with.

Comment: @Pierre Paquette IMore expensive telescopes need collimating and I don't think that would be easy to do.

Comment: This is the telescope I would get for that amount of money: [UK](https://www.firstlightoptics.com/beginner-telescopes/skywatcher-heritage-130p-flextube.html) (£195) [US](https://shop.astronomerswithoutborders.org/products/awb-onesky-reflector-telescope) ($249). It _was_ within your $200 limit until this year when the price of everything shot up :-(

Comment: @Adrdav22: It’s actually not that complicated. There are also refractors and catadioptric telescopes (SCTs, Maksutovs, etc.), that don’t need collimation or can do without…

Comment: @Adrdav22 you can't buy telescopes in the UK denominated in dollars.  Exchange rates vary and I, for one, am not familiar with the exchange rate to dollars at the moment.  As you are not able to buy a telescope in dollars, you should edit your question to use your local currency, ie UKP

Comment: This completely depends on what your expectations are. Saturn is a easy target, in part because its shape is unique so it's obvious what you're seeing, and it adds a high novelty factor. If you want a dot with rings, you can even [use good binoculars](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/36580/which-binocular-should-i-buy-to-be-able-to-see-saturn-and-its-rings). On the other side, you might need to [spend $3 billion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini%E2%80%93Huygens) for a spacecraft to take your pictures.

Answer (score 3):

My simple answer to your question is that you're probably going to have to increase your budget to find something worthwhile.  But there are some options.

For planetary and lunar observing, there's a few key things to keep in mind.  The first is your observing conditions, specifically astronomical seeing.

When we talk about "seeing" we're referring to the steadiness of the air between you and the object you're trying to see. Let's use any fairly bright star as an example.  If you point your scope - regardless of the telescope here - at the star, you'd ideally want to see it as a perfectly steady, sharp point of light that's not moving, flickering, or shifting color.

Regardless of the magnitude of the star (or its actual size and distance), it should appear as a pinpoint of light.  But the atmosphere will alter this appearance.  First, depending on the brightness, the air will scatter some of the light and bloat the star somewhat.  This is why brighter stars appear larger - there's just more light to scatter.

If you're observing a star and its color appears to be shifting -- this is more obvious for stars closer to the horizon -- then there's something in the atmosphere that's causing minor refractions of the light.  In a sense, the air is acting a bit like a prism, and the various wavelengths (i.e. colors) of light are affected slightly differently.  There also may be particulates or gasses in the air that are, in effect, filtering the light a little bit.  As I mentioned, this is more obvious for stars closer to the horizon because when you see them you're looking through a thicker slice of the atmosphere and there's more stuff in the way.

The same thing goes for twinkling.  If the brightness of the star is shifting, this is due to the air and stuff in the air messing with the light reaching your telescope and/or eyes.

Then there's the shifting or dancing of a star.  I remember one incident when I was observing Jupiter (ok, not a star, but the same issues apply).  At low magnification, it was jumping all around the field of view.  This was due to air currents at a higher altitude.

To understand this better, imagine you're standing on the edge of a swimming pool and someone throws a coin in and it settles on the bottom.  If the water is perfectly still, you might be able to see that it's a quarter versus a dime or nickel, or even a half dollar (as uncommon as those are). But what if the water isn't still?  What if someone's swimming around at the other end of the pool and making waves?  You may still be able to see the coin, but not clearly enough to identify it: the image you see is moving around due to the waves and currents in the water.

Air currents have the same effect.  Yes, the air isn't as dense as the water in a pool, but there's a whole lot more of it between you and space.  And while the winds where you are on the surface may be calm, as you go up in altitude, there may be different conditions.  A couple hundred feet above your head there might be a stiff breeze.  A few thousand there might be heavy winds.  Some of those winds may be turbulent, others smoothly flowing.  As the light from whatever star/planet/etc... you're trying to view passes through all of this, the air will refract the light slightly differently - often enough to make for poor seeing conditions.

This is one of the reasons why major observatories are built on top of mountains: it gets them out of the lower, denser, more humid air and away from the worst of the atmospheric conditions in general.

This is regardless of the telescope you're using: it will affect a 50 mm, 500 mm, or 5 m telescope.

Ok, so another consideration is magnification.  This is something that's often misunderstood.  Magnification is important, particularly for planetary observing, but there's things to keep in mind.

For visual observing (i.e. telescope and eyepiece, no camera), you calculate your magnification by dividing the focal length of the telescope by that of the eyepiece used.  If your telescope has a focal length of 1,000 mm (focal length is nearly always expressed in millimeters) and you're using a 25 mm eyepiece, you get a magnification of 40X (1,000 / 25 = 40).  If you switch to a 10 mm eyepiece, you get 100X.  Technically speaking, there is no limit to magnification.  Let's say your shortest eyepiece is 5 mm, with a 1,000 mm telescope that gets you 200X. If you add a 2X Barlow Lens, it effectively doubles the telescope's focal length to 2,000 mm, so you get 400X with your 5 mm eyepiece.  Let's say you add a second Barlow (yes, you can do this, though for several reasons it's probably not worth doing): now you're at 800X.  You can keep doing this as long as you want and keep doubling the magnification.  But at a certain point, all you're doing is magnifying a blur.

This is because while magnification has no limits, detail resolution does.  The amount of detail you can resolve with a given telescope is dependent upon its aperture due to the diffraction of light.  We call this the Diffraction Limit.  The actual calculation for this is specific to a given wavelength of light (e.g. the diffraction limit of a telescope for blue light will be different than that for red light), but we can use a fairly simple formula to get a rough estimate.  This is the formula for Dawes' Limit.  (For those who know about this, yes, it's not really the same, but it's an easy way to get a rough estimate).  To calculate the Dawes' Limit you divide 116 by the aperture in millimeters to get the angular size of the limit in arcseconds.  So for my 80 mm refractors, the Dawes' Limit is 1.45 arcseconds, while my 8 inch SCT gives me 0.57 arcseconds, and my 16 inch Dob gives me 0.29 arcseconds.  This means I should be able to discern details this small through each scope.

So what does that mean for details?  Well, let's take Saturn for example.  The biggest gap in the rings, known as the Cassini Division, is about 4,800 km wide.  So, with my 8 inch telescope, can I see it?  At its closest approach to the Earth, Saturn is about 1.2 billion kilometers away.  At that distance, using a little trigonometry, I can calculate that an angle of 0.57 arcseconds is equal to a linear size of about 3,317 kilometers. Since that's smaller than the Cassini Division, I should be able to see it.  but with my 80 mm refractor, an angle of 1.45 arcseconds gives me a linear size of about 8,439 km, so I shouldn't be able to make it out, or, at least, it will be so blurry as to be difficult to discern.

Again, the Dawes' limit isn't an exact measure to be used here, just a rough guideline (it was actually formulated to determine how far apart two point-sources of light [i.e. stars] have to be separated before you can determine that there's actually two points and not a single one... which is a little bit different, but still depends on angular size/separation).

Since detail is going to be a key concern for planetary observing, aperture is going to be important.  But, again, you have to contend with the atmosphere.

Tele-Vue makes what are frequently considered the best eyepieces on the market (not everyone will agree here, but they're at least near the top of the list).  On their website, they offer a little calculation web app which asks you to enter a couple details about your telescope (any two of these three factors: aperture, focal length, focal ratio) and it will give you a list of performance stats for their various eyepieces.  In the resulting list, you might find some of the magnifications pointing to a footnote that says they recommend up to 60X of magnification per inch of aperture up to a maximum of about 350X regardless of aperture.  This is due to atmospheric effects.  They're essentially saying that 350X is really the best you can hope for with any telescope and they don't recommend going higher.  Since they're essentially telling you to not bother with several of their eyepiece I find this to be good information.  They'd rather you get good performance with what works than waste your money on stuff that won't likely give you good views (though I'm sure they'll happily take your money anyway if you insist on buying them).

To be fair, I've seen great views at higher magnifications a few times.  I was at my club's dark site one night and one of the guys on the field had a 20" Dob and we had great seeing - I don't know what the magnification we viewed Saturn and Mars with, but it was definitely higher than 350X.  But this was an exceptionally good night with a very large telescope, and not something you can expect on a regular basis.

Ok, so what does this mean for you?

First, all other things being equal, you want to get the largest aperture you can afford.  But you should also keep in mind the quality of the optics.  I'd much rather have a Takahashi or Astro-Physics 100 mm apochromatic refractor than an 8 inch Meade or Celestron SCT.  The quality of the optics from a premium brand is going to provide a better view, even if they only have about 1/2 the aperture.

Another important factor is the mount. If you take a smaller aperture telescope on a solid mount and compare it to a larger aperture on less stable mount, the smaller aperture will give a better viewing experience.  This is one of the reasons I STRONGLY recommend against low-price telescopes, especially ones on flimsy tripods.  The Celestron PowerSeeker line comes to mind (some of the worst scopes available  - so bad there's an entire subreddit devoted to how bad they are: [www.reddit.com/r/dontbuyapowerseeker](http://www.reddit.com/r/dontbuyapowerseeker)).

You can find several 114mm (4.5 inch) scopes on the market these days.  Many of them come on tripod-based mounts.  Others come on what are often referred to as "tabletop-Dobsonian" mounts (these are not actually Dobsonian mounts, just simple alt-az mounts, but I'm splitting hairs here).   An example of this is the Orion StarBlast 4.5.  It's a little above your price point (currently on sale for \$230, normally \$250), but would probably beat out what you currently have.

Orion offers a few smaller, and less expensive, similar options, like the SkyScanner BL102, which is a 102 mm (roughly 4 inch) scope. It's in your price range (Currently \$135), but I'm hesitant to outright recommend it.

Generally speaking, unless you're able to afford a premium scope like those from Astro-Physics or Takahashi, I wouldn't recommend anything smaller than about 5 inches (130 mm).  Below that size, a decent pair of binoculars is usually a better buy.  I generally recommend saving up for something like a 6 or 8 inch Dobsonian (I consider an 8 inch Dob the best beginner scope option, and one that will be useful well into your future as you grow in experience).  But if you're bound and determined to get something now,  that's the direction I'd go.

Of course, this doesn't take into account used equipment.  You can find some really good deals on used scopes if you know where to look. Unfortunately, the best and most reliable sites for used gear typically don't offer much in the way of lower-end equipment (you can often save 30% or so on a mount that otherwise would cost \$2,000, but odds are you won't find something like you're looking for).  But if you're a member of a club, then you might well find something in your local club.

And here is where my final and most important piece of advice comes: find and join a local astronomy club or society.

There's several reasons here.  First, most such clubs put on events known as star parties on a relatively regular basis.  At a star party, you're likely to get a chance to look through a wide range of scopes of all sorts of prices, sizes, and quality levels.  This will help you learn more about what you're really looking for, as well as get a chance to see stuff you might not otherwise see.  Many clubs have their own observatory or dark site which members can learn to use, often with some pretty nice equipment available.  And some clubs have loaner telescopes that members can borrow.  On top of that, members of the clubs I'm in or am familiar with are constantly buying/selling/trading equipment between themselves.  Nearly all of my equipment has been bought used from members of my clubs that were selling stuff off to fund their next upgrade or because they were getting out of the hobby.  You might find someone in a local club selling of an older Dob that's in your price range... or at least a decent upgrade from what you have.  And, of course, with most clubs you have a built-in support network to help you learn more.

So I'd hold the money, join a club, and see what options that brings you.  The membership dues for most clubs in the US is under \$50/yr (mostly well under, I pay about \$55 total for membership in the club local to me in New Hampshire and the club where I used to live in Texas).  There are more benefits still, so I'd definitely look into it.

One final recommendation: if you want to learn more about a variety of telescopes, I strongly recommend the [Scope Reviews website](https://www.scopereviews.com/) and [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/@edting) of Ed Ting.  I was aware of Ed's reviews and advise long before moving to NH where I was pleasantly surprised to find out he's a local here and member of the same club I joined.  Ed is well known in the amateur astronomy community and has done reviews on a wide range of telescopes from cheap refractors and Newtonians to high-end premium equipment.  You can take or leave my advice, but you really should listen to Ed, he really knows his stuff.

Good luck and clear skies!

Comment: Use \\$ to prevent Markdown from interpreting text between dollar signs as a MathJax formula.

Comment: Wonderful and *wonderfully thorough* answer (as always!) +1

Answer (score 0):

> Can telescopes under $200 help you see saturn clearly by eye without editing the image on a computer?

> Can a cheap telescope give clear views of Saturn or Jupiter without the need for making videos or taking photos?

Hmm... you might get a great telescope under \$200 by finding a good deal on a *used telescope* that originally cost more, or cost \$200 new *thirty years ago* :-)

But that's probably not what you are asking.

You haven't explained what "clear image" means to you, but I assume you want to see distinct bands of Jupiter (perhaps even the red spot) and maybe the dark spaces between Saturn and its rings when they are at maximum tilt.

For those -- ***by eye*** -- it's Earth's atmosphere that's going to stop you, not the telescope.

Take your low cost telescope to a location and time that has good [astronomical seeing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_seeing) which means has the least atmospheric turbulence both

1. right above you (standing in a still-warm concrete jungle ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urban_area), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Specials_(album))) after sunset as the air cools would be bad)
2. many kilometers higher where astronomical seeing effects are always present.

Usually this means some combination of

- going away from cities
- up in altitude (mountains)
- waiting later into the night

> but the planet's were always badly out of focus

Only after working on those points first will you begin to experience what your telescope can do in terms of resolving the planets. If you haven't found a good place in space and time where "seeing" was good, that could certainly explain your feeling that they were "out of focus".

Also, make sure there was not moisture condensation on your optical surfaces and that they were all clean and free of oil from accidental contact with skin.

Finally, if the images were too bright and you eyes were night-adapted, they might appear a bit washed out. You might consider a filter - neutral density to make them darker, and a color filter may even enhance the contrast between bands of clouds on Jupiter.

**Only after getting familiar with astronomical seeing and checking for dirt and moisture should you just go out and buy a more expensive telescope thinking it will look better!**

My guess is that as long as you want a good visual presentation of the planets without any photography and image sorting/stacking, the internet is where you'll find them, not a telescope eyepiece, *unless you happen to have a perfect night with unusually good astronomical seeing!*